# ifstream not reading input file correctly

Tags: file, loops, input, while-loop, ifstream

I have this fillTable() function which uses ifstream to read input from a file.

```
void dgraph::fillTable()
{
char x = ' ';
slot = 0;
ifstream fin("table.txt");
while (fin >> Gtable[slot].vertexName)
{
    countUsed++;

    while (fin >> Gtable[slot].outDegree)
    {
        int y = 0;
        while (y < Gtable[slot].outDegree)
        {
            fin >> x;
            Gtable[slot].adjacentOnes.addRear(x);
            y++;
        }
    }
    slot++;
}
fin.close();
}
```

the problem is that the main while loop will only execute once. I need it to keep going until there is nothing left in the file. All I've been able to figure out so far is that no indices other than 0 seem to be working. I've tried starting at index 1 and got -52 'Ì' for the vertexName and a -858993460 for the outDegree.

```
    A 2 B F
    B 2 C G
    C 1 H
    E 0
    F 2 I E
    G 0
    H 2 G I
    I 3 A G E
```

this is the input file that I am trying to read into my Gtable. The first letter of each line is the vertexName, the number is the outDegree, and the remaining letters on each line represent the adjacent vertices of the initial vertex. basically I get everything from the first line and then it breaks out of the loop and I am unsure as to why that is. Any help is appreciated.

Comment: WOWOWOWOW!!! just fixed it I know no one has responded to this question yet, but it seems that all I needed was to add a break; statement to the second while loop.

Answer (score 0):

just added break; statement to second loop.

```
while (fin >> Gtable[slot].vertexName)
{
    countUsed++;

    while (fin >> Gtable[slot].outDegree)
    {
        int y = 0;
        while (y < Gtable[slot].outDegree)
        {
            fin >> x;
            Gtable[slot].adjacentOnes.addRear(x);
            y++;
        }
        break;
    }
        slot++;
}
fin.close();
```